# Haskell-Stack error: "The same package name is used in multiple local packages"

Tags: haskell-stack

I have two different Haskell projects on my machine, and each uses the `WordNet` package. When installing [`WordNet` from Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/WordNet) the build failed, however the package did build successfully when cloned and installed locally from [github](https://github.com/pikajude/WordNet-ghc74).

In each of my two projects, I point to the local installation in the `stack.yaml` file as described in the "packages and extra-deps" section of [stack's documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages-and-extra-deps). The first project builds successfully. However, when I attempt to build the second project using this local dependency, I get the following error.

```
$ stack build
The same package name is used in multiple local packages

WordNet used in:
- PLIndex "WordNet-1.1.0"
- PLOther (PLFilePath "../WordNet-ghc74")
```

**Why can I not depend on the same local package in two different projects?**

Is there some way around this?

---

I have tried both cloning the package locally and pointing there in `stack.yaml`,

```
packages:
- .
- ../WordNet-ghc74
```

and also pointing to the repository directly on github in my `stack.yaml`.

```
packages:
- .
- location:
    git: http://github.com/mherzl/WordNet-ghc74.git
    commit: 35478c4ee8ce3fcb7b134901255818408fb934a1
  extra-dep: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same local package in multiple projects. This looks like you have both `WordNet-1.1.0` and the local file path listed in your packages / extra-deps.  If this is not the case, then please open an issue on the stack issue tracker with a reproduction of the problem.  Also, please ensure that you are on the latest stable version of stack (1.6.3)